# Which Java version for Android with different minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion

Tags: java, android, build-tools

When using Gradle to compile my Android applications, how do I determine which Java version to use? For instance, some snippets of my gradle build file look like:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    // Other settings

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22

        // Other default settings
    }
}
```

Java SE 7 is supported for android SDK version 19 and higher, that is for KitKat and above. Given the above snippet, how do I determine whether I should use Java SE 7 or Java SE 6 for compilation and source code compatibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the `minSdkVersion` nor the `targetSdkVersion` are used to determine the source code compatibility for compilation. The determinant for source compatibility and compilation is both the `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`.

I used a gradle file with the following values:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    // Other settings

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 23

        // Other default settings
    }
}
```

A snippet of the code specifically used for test is:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    ...

    List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
    strings.add("John Doe");
    strings.add("Jane Doe");
    strings.add("Bill Gates");
    strings.add("Mark Zuckerberg");

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_gallery_item, strings);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    ...
}
```

When you change the build tools to `buildToolsVersion = '17'` you get an error message:

```
The SDK Build Tools revision (17.0.0) is too low for project ':app'. Minimum required is 19.1.0
```

When you change this to `buildToolsVersion = '19.1.0'`, the build is successful.

When you set the `compileSdkVersion` to any value less than the `buildToolsVersion` major value, build fails, mainly due to missing resource dependencies.

Setting the `minSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to any version below the compileSdkVersion has no effect.

> P.S. 1. Major value is the first integer before the first dot. e.g. `buildToolsVersion '23.0.2'` has major value is 23.
>
> P.S. 2. I tested the results of a successful build with a real device with Android API Level 10, (Gingerbread 2.3.6). I set source code compatibility to JDK 7, and used the Diamond Operator introduced in Java 7.